# GTM GA4 Configuration Tag blocks UA GTM tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, event-tracking, google-analytics-4

I've ran into a problem that I've never seen before and I'm in dire need of help on this one.

I've setup some GA4 tags for a single-page application which caused my UA tags to change status to "Still Running" and not sending data to my UA properties. This only happens to the UA tags fired **after** the GA4 configuration tag is fired:

[screenshot of the second virtual pageview Data Layer event fired on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJznv.png)

There aren't any tags affected by our GA4 tag besides the UA tags. GA4 event tags fire completely fine too.

*Other information:* I'm quite experience with GTM. We're firing our tags on dataLayer events that signify virtual page views. I've tried everything I could think of to check if I could run both UA & GA tags at the same time, but nothing worked.

I thought that the ga() method might've been hijacked so I even tried to check that by posting on the console the following:

> console.log(window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']].answer);

But the response was "42" which means that the analytics.js library is still working with the global method (thanks Simo Ahava for the tip).

P.S. I'm not running Google Optimize on the website which is a well-known thing that might cause this issue.

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a CutomTask in your UA settings?
I had the same issue and couldnt find the solution, I have found that a CutomTask running a clientID event before the UA payload was the reason to this problem.